# How can I read a file and return the content as the result of a function?

Tags: file, vbscript

I have two functions on Visual Basic for read and write one file

The problem is in the read Function. The `return` sentence doesn't return anything. I only want read the first line of the file

What Am i doing wrong? Why does the `return` not put the value in the text variable?

```
Function readfile()

    Dim objFSO
    Dim objLF
    Dim text

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     

    on error resume next 
    Set objLF= objFSO.OpenTextFile ("file.txt",1,false)

    if Err.Number <> 0 Then

        Wscript.echo "error"

    else

        text = objLF.ReadLine  
        objLF.Close
        return text

    end if



    On Error Goto 0 

End Function
```

Comment: `on error resume next` <-- never do this.

Comment: why? what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return text` is not Visual Basic but C (and derived languages like JScript). So it should be `ReadFile=Text`, The name of the function is equal to the return value in all Basics.

Your use of `on error` is appropriate, but you should use `On Error Goto 0` to turn it off after the open file operation.

To

> To return a value from a function, assign the value to the function
> name. Any number of such assignments can appear anywhere within the
> procedure. If no value is assigned to name, the procedure returns a
> default value: a numeric function returns 0 and a string function
> returns a zero-length string (""). A function that returns an object
> reference returns Nothing if no object reference is assigned to name
> (using Set) within the Function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement

Help file is at http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Comment: Then, Is it the solution? @user14122392

Function readfile()

Dim objFSO
Dim objLF
Dim text

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     

on error resume next 
Set objLF= objFSO.OpenTextFile ("file.txt",1,false)

if Err.Number <> 0 Then

Wscript.echo "error"

else

     text = objLF.ReadLine  
     objLF.Close
     readfile= text

end if
   On Error Goto 0 
 
     End Function

Comment: What happened when you tried it. I'm not sure why you are asking me what happened when you tried it.

Comment: already works, thank you. I already have work one part of the program. Now i need help with the Write function. I want overwrite only the first line. 


 on error resume next
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objWF = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("file.txt",2,false)

 if Err.Number <> 0 Then

  Wscript.echo "error"  

 else
  textfile = objWriteFile.Write(readfile())
  objWF.close
  Wscript.echo textfile 
 end if
 
 On Error Goto 0

Note: All need variable are declarated

Comment: @Nephilina Please don't post code in comments. That is not readable at all. If you have a new question you should post it as a question.